# run time error 35601 element not found

Tags: vb6

I released an upgrade to my VB6 application and I get this error on some screens at run time.  The problem seems to depend on the data.  The problem does not happen on the previous version of my application.  Thus I am wondering what the error means

Comment: I am voting to close this as it is far to ambiguous.  The actual error message is telling you what is wrong but from what you have posted no one could help you with why you are getting it.

Comment: I agree... but I am waiting on more information myself. Hopefully I will be able to provide more information tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to do with listview.

I had item declared as a MSComctlLib.ListItem

the code failed at

```
item.ListSubItems("Deliver").Bold = True
```

because I had no such column heading.